# How to remove folder from Rails autoload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

in my application people can upload files with paperclip. One user stored a ruby script, which is placed in a folder like `app/assets/assignment_attachments`.

Sadly, when my application tries to start it executes this ruby script which doesn't work, because it includes stuff my application doesn't know.

The question is: How can I stop Rails from autoloading this files? I tried the following in my `config/application.rb` without success:

```
 config.eager_load_paths -= [Dir["#{config.root}/app/assets/assignment_attachments/**"]]
 config.autoload_paths -= [Dir["#{config.root}/app/assets/assignment_attachments/**"]]
```

How do I exclude those files from beeing executed?

Kind regards,

Nils

Comment: Have you tried doing something like: config.autoloads_path.reject! {|p| p if p == Dir[...]}

Comment: You're probably better off not allowing files to be uploaded in to app.  I'd move the assignment attachments elsewhere, and (if possible) add a Paperclip AttachmentContentTypeValidator to ensure that you're getting the types of files uploaded that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think uploaded files should be stored in your `app` folder as this is used – as the name says – for your app code.

The default is to use `public/system` that can be symlinked to e.g. `/www/myapp/shared/system` (for example if you use [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) for deployment) to be shared between deploys.

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage for help.